# Why is the <a> text purple on load?

Tags: html, css

So I've create a simple website, and when reloading it, the menu is purple and the text in the middle is black. But then after about half a second they all change their color to normal. Why does that happen and how can I change it? Thanks.

Purple Text on Load (Image):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL15i.png

And also, the problem disappears after I remove the transition attribute.

```css
.menu a {
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.menu a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu h1 {
  color: white;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: aqua;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#footer">Works</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the default color for visited links

Comment: Can you include the HTML as well? I can't seem to reproduce the problem from what you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code but make sure about your `index.html`.

```css
.menu a {
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition-duration: 1s;

}

.menu a:visited { 
 text-decoration: none; 

}

.menu h1 {
    color: white;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: aqua;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<a class="active" href="#footer">Home</a>
<a href="#footer">Works</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove transition-duration: 1s from menu a {}. It will solved easily. Because it's taking 1 second to loading this class.

Comment: They specifically said that "the problem disappears after I remove the transition attribute" so presumably they don't want to do that.

Comment: The thing is, I am just using transition for when the user will hover on the menu, so it will be light blue. And, it doesn't look as good as it was with transition.